# Sockets between Raspbian-Windows openCV videostream

Tags: python, c++, sockets, opencv

This is my first time asking here but I've been looking around for a solution long time and I've been unable to find it, so I will try to solve this and, if more people have the same problem, help those with this thread. Hope it is not duplicated exactly!

I have a server in Windows7, C++, Visual Studio 2015, where I have some routines running in openCV. I'm taking some of those tasks out from my computer to a remote Raspberry Pi 3, so I programmed a client in Python 3 which uses sockets as well.

Both the server (C++) and the client (Python) are properly working when sending strings such as "Hello World!" and that stuff. The problem came when I started to send binary data.

I have an image in openCV (client-python side) and I used imencode function:

```
data = cv2.imencode(".jpg", image, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90])[1].tostring()
```

Then I have a buffer where I'm storing the information to be sent, so I add that data to the buffer:

```
buffer.append(data)
```

Then, when the buffer is populated, I sent the first image through my socket client:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect("some_address and some port")
sock.send(data)
sock.close()
```

In the meanwhile, in the server side (C++), I initialized the windows socket, solved the address, created a listening socket, linking the listening socket to the server address and the wait for the client to connect to the listening socket. When the client connects, the listening socket is closed and I call to start receiving method:

```
do {
    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        totalBytes += iResult;
        std::cout << recvbuf << std::endl;
        ss << recvbuf;

        std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Bytes received: " << iResult << std::endl;

        // Echo the buffer back to the sender
        iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
        if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "send failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "Bytes sent: " << iSendResult << std::endl;
    }
    else if (iResult == 0) {
        std::cout << "Connection closing..." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "recv failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        break;
    }
} while (iResult > 0);
addData(ss.str());
```

Then, addData pushes back the information received into a queue buffer (inside a mutex region), casted as uint8:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> v(data.begin(), data.end());
lck.lock();
buffer.push(v);
lck.unlock();
```

From another part of my program, I'm reading (as well inside a mutex region) the oldest element in that queue

```
std::vector<uint8_t> & ImageServer::getNextImage()
{
    lck.lock();
    if (buffer.size() > 0)
    {
        frameJPG = buffer.front();
        buffer.pop();
    }

    lck.unlock();
    return frameJPG;
}
```

and I try to decode it using openCV function again:

```
try {
    vec = is->getNextImage();
    img = cv::imdecode(vec, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    if (img.data == NULL)
        std::cout << "Image in buffer couldn't be properly decoded" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "IMAGE RECOVERED!" << std::endl;
} catch (...) {
    std::cout << "AN UNKNOWN ERROR OCURRED" << std::endl;
}
```

It is always going into img.data == NULL. That means that there is not enough data (not the case) or the data can't be properly formatted. Why? I'm messing things up when storing it into a stringstream as a first buffer to gather the whole data stream? It is split into 1024 bytes packages...

I've checked:

1. Size of the received data in the server equals to data size in the client side.
2. b"Hello World!" strings are being properly sent and received.
3. Both Raspbian and Windows 7 are little endian
4. Both OpenCV installations are openCV3.x

After 1000 different test with different castings I'm stuck just in the same point: a binary stream which I cannot parse. Does OpenCV behave in a different way in Windows and in Python so it is not able to decode in C++ what was encoded in Python? Do sockets receive information unsorted? Do the sockets add some header that I have to trim in some way? Is it caused by the OS architecture (x86 vs x64)?

Thank you so much in advance.

If you need more code, I can post it too, but I would like to keep it clean!

Regards,
maije

Comment: TL;DR; You are aware about endianess and how to normalize data between different machine architectures, when sending it over the wire?

Comment: Seems that the vec that you pass to cv::imdecode is invalid for it. Something has damaged, cut, added incorrect bytes or reordered it on the way. So perhaps try to give it correct data locally and when it succeeds then try to give same data over network and then check in what step and what does damage it. We don't have your full code so we can't do it for you.

Comment: When you find out what damages the bytes but do not understand why then come back and see that specific question is most likely already answered here.

Comment: I am not familiar with how Windows does things but you should be aware that you don't always receive exactly what you ask for with sockets, sometimes the data are split by switches and routers, so you normally have to keep receiving in a loop and adding whatever you receive to whatever you received before until you get all that you want or need. Just because you ask for 1024 bytes does not mean you will get 1024, you may get 53 and have to do another receive, or another 7 receives.

Comment: Yep πάντα ῥεῖ , Point 3 in the list :-)

Comment: Thank you  Öö Tiib, yes, I have to do some tests related to that like do it in localhost and program both sides in python, but it will take me some time and I just wanted to ask here to see if there was an OpenCV issue which the community already knew and therefore help others stucked in the same point :-) When I come to a solution, I will post it here as well ;-)

Comment: Dear Mark Setchell, yes, I'm aware. The packet size is 1024, but my images are been splited in those packages (as much as they need) and I add a termination string to check when an image has been totally sent. In the recv method there is a do-while loop. In addition, I'm currently doing an echo from the server to check if the data sent and the data received from both sides has the same size, and it is :-) I will switch it to an ACK later, when everything is comming together!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your bytes get cut with `ss << recvbuf;` since `<<` treats that `recvbuf` as null-terminated string. Instead it should be treated as buffer that contains `iResult` bytes. That means that it is not null-terminated, its last byte may be anything and there may be null values in middle of it.

I suggest to drop that `ss` and instead to build a `std::vector<uint8_t>` directly from pieces received in `recvbuf`.

You can insert all contents of `recvbuf` to end of vector `v` like that:

```
v.insert(v.end(), recvbuf, recvbuf + iResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes!, Öö Tiib, that was it. On Friday I was suspicious about that, and you are right. This morning I changed it and it worked smoothly, without any other modification in the code but in the add and the get data methods! (to fit into the new data structure).

So here it is as I'm doing it in a first test:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> v;
// Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
do {
    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        totalBytes += iResult;
        for (auto i = 0; i < iResult; ++i)
            v.push_back(recvbuf[i]);
    //some more lines unreleated to the answer
```

Is there any more efficient way to fill the vector v?
Thank you so much in advance for your very appreciated help on this!

PS: I'm so sorry I cannot upvote your answer since I have no reputation to do so :-(

Comment: I add suggestion how to fill vector to my answer. Usually it looks better and can be more efficient than hand-made for loop.